# Intellij IDEA: The Google Play services resources were not found

Tags: android, intellij-idea, admob

Please help! I'm working in Intellij IDEA, and there is no good of all that techniques that i found for preventing this Google Services errors,

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

i'm started using new Admob and it's problems killing me(((

This is the error i got before app brings me out...

```
02-18 03:05:13.896    9339-9339/com.xxx.xxx E/ActivityThread﹕ Activity com.xxx.xxx.ActIntentionDailyProgress has leaked ServiceConnection azc@427d8c80 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.xxx.xxx.ActIntentionDailyProgress has leaked ServiceConnection azc@427d8c80 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:981)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:875)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1494)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1482)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:496)
            at wr.b(SourceFile:92)
            at wr.a(SourceFile:121)
            at tt.d(SourceFile:88)
            at tt.b(SourceFile:129)
            at tq.a(SourceFile:239)
            at tq.a(SourceFile:176)
            at zv.a(SourceFile:117)
            at aay.run(SourceFile:14)
            at aba.run(SourceFile:30)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-18 03:05:13.896    9339-9364/com.xxx.xxx W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b6e8b0)
02-18 03:05:13.896     843-1334/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@437ae860
02-18 03:05:13.896    9339-9364/com.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AdWorker #2
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: azc@427d8c80
            at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:933)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1527)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:508)
            at wr.a(SourceFile:135)
            at tt.d(SourceFile:88)
            at tt.b(SourceFile:129)
            at tq.a(SourceFile:239)
            at tq.a(SourceFile:176)
            at zv.a(SourceFile:117)
            at aay.run(SourceFile:14)
            at aba.run(SourceFile:30)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Please help, what i supposed to do?

Comment: As @hunterp says it's a bug. Check this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/sePctoDJbRg